# What container to use to get such layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Look at the sketch layout.

[image]

I need to have 5 buttons located in the middle of the screen and arranged like this. What kind of container element should I use - `TableLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or some 3rd layout?

Comment: if this is homework, remember to use the homework flag.

Comment: Well, no, just a part of more complex layout :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation i would use something like this

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ....>
    <RelativeLayout ... >
        // place the buttons in the desired padding
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout ... >
        <Button ... android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" ... />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout ... >
        // place the buttons in the desired padding
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Relative Layout,

Step 1: Create your first Button then create the second button make the second Button  leftof  to first Button

Step2:  Create the third button below to the first Button

Step 3: Create the fourth and fifth button below to the third button

Answer (score 0):

I suggest elements with a relative position (or an absolute one, it depends on if it's in a container or not)

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you always want them in rows like you show, but don't want them in columns, I wouldn't go for a TableLayout. A RelativeLayout is good.

Or, how about combining layouts like so? I just whipped this up (see the `android:gravity` properties to see how it works):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What about the space between buttons? This way they will touch each others, right?!

Comment: How much of a space did you want? You didn't say that in your question. :P If you view that layout as-is in Eclipse, you should see that they don't touch in appearance, but the rectangles that they can be touched in does. If you want them to have more space between them, specify margins on each button or on each sublayout, depending on what you need. Remember to use dp units and not px. :)